# How to point to the latest revision in the branch from the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have the following gem definition in the Gemfile and the lock file, I dont want a revision in the lock file and I want it to point to the latest revision in the branch. How do I do?

```
gem 'mygem', git: "git@github.com:myorg/mygem.git", branch: 'master'


GIT 
  remote: git@github.com:myorg/mygem.git
  revision: 423b414404572fe68deaca6d41684bdffb6b9bf4
  branch: master
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to specify version:

```
gem 'mygem', '1.0', github: "myorg/mygem", branch: 'master'
```

or tag:

```
gem 'mygem', github: "myorg/mygem", branch: 'master', tag: 'v1.0'
```

or even ref:

```
gem 'mygem', github: "myorg/mygem", branch: 'master', ref: '0eec4'
```

Take a look at these examples: http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html

Comment: No its still not clear, I just reference the gem (not sure what the version is) and I want it to pick up pretty much all changes from that particular branch and not a revision of the branch as mentioned by the Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: The problem is I need to do this whenever someone commits a change for mygem, how should I avoid it

Comment: Is there a definitive answer for this

Comment: You could install gem once for desired branch/version. When gem will be locked into Gemfile.lock then you will use particular version of the gem (wish has been locked). Avoid using `bundle update` to keep locked gem version.